# How to mutate a value from a callback?

Tags: rust

Really sorry about the basic question.

I am trying to simulate something like a web server call and capture a variable from an outer scope.

```
fn http_get(path: &str, f: &dyn Fn()) {
  f();
}


fn main() {
  let mut counter = 0;

  http_get("/foo", &|| {
    counter = counter + 1;
    println!("/foo: {}", counter);
  });
  
  http_get("/bar", &|| {
    counter = counter + 1;
    println!("/bar: {}", counter);
  });
}
```

This results in a compiler error `cannot assign to 'counter', as it is a captured variable in a 'Fn' closure`.

I know I am failing somewhere basic, any chance I could get a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to explain why this does not work.

When you transfer your `counter` into the closure, you basically allow other code to use it at any time. If it's just one closure, you can `move` it into the closure, giving the ownership of the value to the inner function, and it will work fine, including mutations, because there is no way to violate borrow checker rules.

Now when you have two closures that must use the same value, and you want to have mutable references to the `counter` in both of them, borrow checker cannot know when this mutable references are dropped. The function, that uses your closure can save the closure for later. Then you would have two mutable reference to the same value at the same time, which is not allowed by the borrow checker.

There are several solutions to this situations.

1. If you don't send your closure across threads, you can use `RefCell`. It provides inner mutability, so even you don't pass mutable reference to a closure, you still can mutate the value of `counter`. The borrow checker rules in this case a checked in runtime. If your code would try to get two mutable references at the same time, not dropping previous one, your code will `panic`.

```
fn http_get(path: &str, f: &dyn Fn()) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let counter = 0;
    let r = std::cell::RefCell::new(counter);

    http_get("/foo", &|| {
        let mut counter = r.borrow_mut();
        *counter = *counter + 1;
        println!("/foo: {}", counter);
    });

    http_get("/bar", &move || {
        let mut counter = r.borrow_mut();
        *counter = *counter + 1;
        println!("/bar: {}", counter);
    });
}
```

2. If you need to cross thread boundaries, you can use `Arc` and `Mutex` as @Zeppi answer suggests.
3. If you work with multiple threads and the value you need to mutate is as simple as `counter`, you should probably use `Arc` and [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/). They allow mutable access from multiple threads without locking.

Comment: Thank you for this, really helpful! How does the Rust compiler know if a callback is executed across thread boundaries and requires an `Arc` rather than in `RefCell`?

Comment: It can track calls down to thread::spawn. If it sees, that your value will be moved into this function (or any analogue) down the call tree, it will require your value to be `Sync`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `move` keyword to capture a closure’s environment by value (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html).

But, for mutable you need to implement Mutex and Arc.

Like this

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn http_get(path: &str, f: &dyn Fn()) {
  f();
}

fn main() {
  let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(5));

  let c = Arc::clone(&counter);
  http_get("/foo",  &( move || {
    let mut c = c.lock().unwrap();
    *c += 1;
    println!("/foo: {}", c);
  }));
  
  let c = Arc::clone(&counter);
  http_get("/bar",  &( move || {
    let mut c = c.lock().unwrap();
    *c += 1;
    println!("/bar: {}", c);
  }));
}
```

Comment: How is it that you can declare `c` twice in the same code block? Is it because the value is moved into the following closure and out of the scope of `main`?

Comment: Yes, is the scoping rules. If you do `fn main() { let x=3; { let x = 4; } println!("{}", x); }` it print 3.